# How to add SDK 1.8 to the exported jar file (Intellij jave)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to export my program as an executable jar. However, when I run it I keep getting a message:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application.

I suspect this is because the SDK 1.8 which includes the `javafx/application/Application` isn't included in the jar (I searched for it in a jar, it's not there).

How can I include it?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX. Packaging JavaFX app so that it works on all the systems is not that simple.

Comment: I just need to somehow add javafx/application/application in my program. Can you please give me a maven dependency for that. The maven dependencies on javafx that I have found so far don't include application class.

Comment: See https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven.